# Video Upload and display on a Django Website

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model where I upload a video, i want to display the same in the browser but somehow I am not able to. Kindly help me.

I made an app with the name deploy, where I am uploading the video and saving it. Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong and what should be done here. I want the video which was uploaded should be displayed on the page and there should be a option for download as well. I shall be extremely thankful for the help.

My models.py file:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    Video_Description= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='deploy/videos/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ("deploy:detail", kwargs={"slug":self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Video_Description + ": " + str(self.id)
```

My views.py file is:

```
class VideoDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()



class VideoListView(ListView):

    paginate_by = 10  # <app>/<modelname>_list.html 

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Video.objects.all()
        print(self.request.GET)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(Video_Description__icontains=query) | Q(videofile__icontains=query))
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(VideoListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        return context
```

video_list.html file is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'deploy/cafeteria_cut.mp4' %} ">

{% block content %}

{% include "result/navbar.html" %}<br/>
{% include "result/sidebar.html" %}<br/>
{% include "result/calendar.html" %}<br/>


<div style="margin-left: 10%">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"><a href="{% url 'deploy:create' %}" style='color:white'>Upload Video</a></button>
</div>


{% for object in object_list %} 


<div class="container" style="margin-left: 10%; align-items: center;">

<h2>

</br>

<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">

{{ object.Video_Description }}

</a>

</br> 

</h2> 

</br>

<a href="" style="align-items: center;"> 

{{ object.videofile}} 

</a> 

</br> 

<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src="{% static 'deploy/youtubeVideo_cut20.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>

 {% empty %}
            {% if request.GET.q %}
            <p style="padding-left: 20%; font-size: 70px">No Result Found </p>
            {% else %}
            <p style="padding-left: 20%; font-size: 70px"> No Result Yet.

            {% endif %}

{% endfor %} 


 {% endblock content %}
```

I am extremely sorry i failed to mention a very important thing, in my video_list.html file, when I do:

```
<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src="{% static 'deploy/youtubeVideo_cut20.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
```

I am getting video displayed on the browser.

Comment: 'but somehow I am not able to'? Can you elaborate what you are not able to do? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Sanip What I meant is that the video which is uploaded is not getting displayed on the browser.

Comment: Try using `src="{{ object.videofile.url }}"` instead of `src="{% static 'deploy/object.videofile' %}"`

Comment: in your browser go with right click -> inspect element -> check the source of the video and the path is probably broken somehow. You can work your way up from this point

Comment: @hansTheFranz it does say " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ", but I dont understand, I tried <source src="{{ object.videofile.url }}" type='video/mp4'> which is the right way but it didnt helped.

Comment: @Aakash can you post the full template?

Comment: @Sanip Sure, here you go

Comment: @Aakash Can you check if the video file is being saved in the path that you specified? Maybe you are configuring the upload_to path incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have maintained the media file settings. In your settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_root")
```

Then in your main `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then make changes in your html file:

```
<source src="{% static 'deploy/object.videofile' %}" type='video/mp4'> //here
```

You are trying to fetch the video file as an static file. This is not the correct approach.

Try passing the url of the object's video file in the `src` of the video as:

```
<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src="{{ object.videofile.url }}" type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
```

Comment: I am sorry to inform that I have tried this already, but it didnt helped.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the source file path being displayed in your html page?

Comment: Which view renders the `video_list.html` template? And are you passing `Video.objects.all()` in a `DetailView`? Also no model specified in the `VideoDetailView`

Comment: kindly check the edit I made, if it might help in better understanding the problem. This is how I am doing it:                                                                                          
class VideoCreateView(CreateView):
 form_class = VideoModelForm
 template_name = 'deploy/create_view.html'
 success_url = reverse_lazy("deploy:list")

Comment: you said no model specified in VideoDetailView. Would you please explain what is the need for it? I have just started working on Django, so i'll be thankful for the explanation.

Comment: `DetailView` is meant for just passing the detail for a single object. Here you have passed all the objects of the `Video` object. This is not what `DetailView` is meant for. For better understanding, refer to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: @Aakash have a look at my edited answer if you have not set the settings for the media file. Else make sure the file is saved in the path specified.